# Jump to equation by label in auctex

Tags: auctex, reftex-mode

While writing latex I sometimes have to reference an equation. I do that using `reftex-reference` (bound to <kbd>C-c (</kbd>  by default). However, I sometimes want to copy some text from the equation text I just referenced.

Ideally, I would like to position my pointer at the equation label and hit some keys to jump to that equation text, or maybe show the equation text in some temporary buffer so that I can copy text from it.

Is there such a functionality in reftex or any other package?

Note: I know I can use reftex table of contents to navigate to the label, but I am hoping I can use the text I already have written to jump to that label.

Answer (score 2):

Reftex has this feature. It's called `reftex-view-crossref`.
See the manual about this [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/reftex/Viewing-Cross_002dReferences.html). 
It is invoked by pressing `C-c &` while your pointer is on the argument of the `\ref{argument}`.

Comment: Can you elaborate? Is it bound to any key by default?